# How do I extract values from each of the values in a map of maps?

Tags: clojure

I've just started learning Clojure, if I define the following map:

```
(def distributions {:normal {:title "Normal" :mean 0 :sd 1}
                    :beta   {:title "Beta" :a 1 :b 3}
                    :gamma  {:title "Gamma" :rate 1/2 :shape 1}})
```

how would I write `(defn get-titles [] ...)` a function that would return
`("Normal", "Beta", "Gamma")`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
(defn get-titles [] (map :title (vals distributions)))
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively: `(for [[k v] distr] (:title v))`